# Wrong date fetch with eloquentt from MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

I get wrong date from MongoDB using Eloquent in Laravel. My record in database looks like this

```
 "created_at" : ISODate("2020-11-17T15:30:42.131+01:00")
```

Code to get records from MongoDB

```
$taskObj = TaskComments::where('task_id', $task_id)->get()->toArray();
```

Result date for **created_at** is

1970-01-25 20:31:23 which is wrong, I would like to get in this format 2020-11-17 15:30:42

I would like to create correct Mutator or to define a default date format in Laravel or in MongoDb I am not sure.

**Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed my problem, I used a mutator in Model of TaskComments

```
   public $timestamps = FALSE;


public function getCreatedAtAttribute($created_at){
    return $created_at->toDateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```